Proving a quadratic transformation of ${}_2F_1$
For context, please see this MSE post
I want to prove that
$${}_2F_1\left(a,b;a−b+1;z\right)=(1−z)^{1−2b}(1+z)^{2b−a−1}{}_2F_1\left[\frac{a−2b+1}{2},\frac{a−2b+2}{2};a−b+1;\frac{4z}{(1+z)^2}\right]$$
The comment said I can prove this by showing that both sides satisfy the same hypergeometric differential equation. However, when I actually tried it out the expression became extremely tedious and I failed to prove the identity using such method. Furthermore, using
hypergeometric differential equation to prove quadratic transformations feel forced and unnatural way.
I would like a proof, preferably that doesn't use the hypergeometric differential equation. If there isn't one, a proof using hypergeometric differential equation would suffice.
Any help is appreciated

Here is a brute force proof using the definition of the ${}_2F_1$. Move the factor $(1-z)^{1-2b}$ to the LHS and expand both sides as series in $z$. On the left, we get
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(1-2b)_k}{k!}\,z^k\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(a)_m(b)_m}{m!(a-b+1)_m}\,z^m. $$
Put $k+m=n$ and pull the sum in $m$ inside. You get
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(1-2b)_n}{n!}\,z^n\sum_{m=0}^n\frac{(a)_m(b)_m(-n)_m}{m!(a-b+1)_m(2b-n)_m}.$$
The inner sum is computed by the Pfaff-Saalschütz summation and we end up with
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(1-b)_n(a-2b+1)_n}{n!(a-b+1)_n}\,z^n.$$
The right-hand side can be written
\begin{multline*}\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(a-2b+1)_{2m}}{m!(a-b+1)_m}\frac{z^m}{(1+z)^{a+1-2b+2m}}\\
=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(a-2b+1)_{2m}}{m!(a-b+1)_m}\,
z^m\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(a-2b+1+2m)_k}{k!}\,(-z)^k.
\end{multline*}
Again we put $k+m=n$ and pull $m$ inside. This gives
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(a-2b+1)_n}{n!}(-z)^n
\sum_{m=0}^n\frac{(a-2b+1+n)_{m}(-n)_m}{m!(a-b+1)_m}.
$$
The inner sum is computed by the Chu-Vandermonde summation and we get the same expression
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(1-b)_n(a-2b+1)_n}{n!(a-b+1)_n}\,z^n$$
as before.
